# why am I not able to add input text into my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to add in text that the user types into the input and have it be added into my table as  with a button that removes the item here is my html code:

```
<table id="proxy-list">
    <tr>
      <!--<th>Name</th> -->
      <th colspan="3">Proxies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proxy1:</td>
      <td>174.32.116.214:87</td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" id="proxy-add-name" placeholder="Name"></input>
  <input type="text" id="proxy-add-proxy" placeholder="Proxy"></input>
  <button type="submit" id="proxy-add" onclick="addProxy()">Add</button>
```

and here is the javascript code I tried that isn't working

```
function addProxy() {
    var proxyName = $('#proxy-add-name').val();
    var proxy = $('#proxy-add-proxy').val();
    $('#proxy-list').append('<tr>'
        +'<td>'+proxyName+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+proxy+'</td>'
        +'<button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button>'
        +'</tr>');
}

$(function(){
  $('#proxy-add').click(function(){
    addProxy();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Any Idea why this isnt working? and how would I add in the text with the remove button so that when I click the button it removes the text?

Any Help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: 1. You don't need both `onclick` and `.click()`. I advise you to use `.click()` only. 2. Maybe not an issue, but still: you are adding button without wrapping it in `<td>`

Comment: What does that mean wrapping it in??  @AlexYokisama

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything works:

1. Deleted `onclick`, only jQuery handler left.
2. Wrapped `button` in `<td>`.
3. Changed `button#proxy-add` type to `button`.

Note 1. Html table may only contain `tr's`. `tr` may only contain `td's`

Note 2. Using `submit` be sure that page is not reloaded.

```js
function addProxy() {
    var proxyName = $('#proxy-add-name').val();
    var proxy = $('#proxy-add-proxy').val();
    $('#proxy-list').append('<tr>'
        +'<td>'+proxyName+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+proxy+'</td>'
        +'<td><button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button></td>'
        +'</tr>');
}

$(function(){
  $('#proxy-add').click(function(){
    addProxy();
    return false;
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.remove-btn', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="proxy-list">
    <tr>
      <!--<th>Name</th> -->
      <th colspan="3">Proxies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proxy1:</td>
      <td>174.32.116.214:87</td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" id="proxy-add-name" placeholder="Name"></input>
  <input type="text" id="proxy-add-proxy" placeholder="Proxy"></input>
  <button type="button" id="proxy-add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to remove the event handler from the button tag for two reasons: to NOT fire the `addProxy()` function twice and, second, because inline event handlers are really bad practice i really ask you to avoid using them.

```
<table id="proxy-list">
    <tr>
      <!--<th>Name</th> -->
      <th colspan="3">Proxies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proxy1:</td>
      <td>174.32.116.214:87</td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" id="proxy-add-name" placeholder="Name"></input>
  <input type="text" id="proxy-add-proxy" placeholder="Proxy"></input>
  <button type="submit" id="proxy-add">Add</button>
```

Your `addProxy()` function works correctly, it just need to add a unique identifier to each new `tr` and to do that I give each `tr` a `data-id` attribute that would be calculated by the script to make it unique, for now and for simplicity, an integer that increment each click would suffice.
You only need now how to make the remove buttons functional. Here's the new `addPtoxy()` function:

```
function addProxy(id) {

    var proxyName = $('#proxy-add-name').val();
    var proxy = $('#proxy-add-proxy').val();
    $('#proxy-list').append('<tr data-id="id-' + id + '">'
        +'<td>'+proxyName+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+proxy+'</td>'
        +'<td><button class="remove-btn" data-target="id-' + id + '"><span class="thex">x</span></button></td>'
        +'</tr>');
}
```

and for the click handler:

```
$('#proxy-add').click(function(){
    addProxy(id++);
    return false;
});
```

**Ps:** the `id` variable must be global and equals to 0 for example.

And for the remove process i'll make it as an anonymous function directly in the click handler:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.remove-btn', function(){
    $('tr[data-id="'+$(this).data('target')+'"]')[0].remove();
    return false;
});
```

**Ps:** here we have to use the `.on` method and attach the event to the `body` and to specify the second argument as `button.remove-btn` because we're working with dynamically added elements.

Comment: It seems as if my code doesn't have a definite border shape so if I remove the first table data the border disappears and is only around the proxies label is there anyway I could email my entire code??

Comment: Im getting this on my terminal when I try and add some text Electron Helper[50213:3833751] Couldn't set selectedTextBackgroundColor from default ()

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {

    function addProxy() {

        var proxyName = $('#proxy-add-name').val();
        var proxy     = $('#proxy-add-proxy').val();
        
        var html      = '<tr>';
        html          += '<td>'+proxyName+'</td>';
        html          += '<td>'+proxy+'</td>';
        html          += '<td>';
        html          += '<button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button>';
        html          += '</tr>';

        $('#proxy-list-body').append(html);
    }

    function resetProxyInputs() {

        $('#proxy-add-name').val('');
        $('#proxy-add-proxy').val('');
    }

    $('#proxy-add').on('click', function(event) {
        addProxy();
        resetProxyInputs();
    });


    $('#proxy-list').on('click', '.remove-btn', function(evnet) {

        var $removeButton = $(this);

        $removeButton.closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
#proxy-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 60%;
  border: 5px solid #e83737;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #e83737;
  text-align: center;
}
th, td {
  color: #4F8AFF;
}
td {
  height: 180px;
  padding-bottom:  140px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.remove-btn {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4F8AFF;
  border: 2px solid #4F8AFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.thex {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.203px;
  left: -0.8px;
}
#proxy-add-name, #proxy-add-proxy {
  position: relative;
  top: 245px;
  left: 60.5%;
  height: 26.5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #e83737;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #4F8AFF;
}
#proxy-add-name {
 width: 90px;
}
#proxy-add-proxy {
  width: 157px;
 border-right: none;
 left: 60%;
}

#proxy-add {
  position: absolute;
  top: 290px;
  left: 84.8%;
  width: 37px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #e83737;
  border: 2px solid #e83737;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <table id="proxy-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Proxies</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="proxy-list-body">
        <tr>
            <td>Proxy1:</td>
            <td>174.32.116.214:87</td>
            <td>
                <button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">x</div></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="text" id="proxy-add-name" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" id="proxy-add-proxy" placeholder="Proxy" />
    <button type="submit" id="proxy-add">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work Ill share my css as-well @chebaby

Comment: I don't see how the CSS style is related to your problem!! any way, what is the thing that it's not working like you would expect it to do?! be more specific.

Comment: I type in the stuff into both the input boxes then I press the add button and nothing happens the text still stays in the input box and I dont see it appear anywere @chebaby

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj ok, let me check and get back to you.

Comment: It may have something to do with the entire code or something like that if you wouldn't mind could I email you the code and you check it out? I don't want to give out my entire code on stack   @chebaby

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj, i updated my answer, if it doesn't answer your question, then you could communicate me your code.

Comment: would I be able to email you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177911/discussion-between-chebaby-and-maxym-wojnowskyj).